# GWT Eclipse Plugin end of beta phase?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

**Background:** The old official Eclipse plugin recommended for GWT development is the **Google Plugin for Eclipse** (aka **GPE**), which, [according to their website](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/), is reaching it's end of support:

*"The Google Plugin for Eclipse is deprecated and will be removed in January 2018. Migrate to Cloud Tools for Eclipse and/or the GWT Eclipse Plugin as soon as possible to avoid disruption."*

So, now they suggest using the **GWT Eclipse Plugin** instead, which is considered (drumroll) to be **beta quality**:

*"This plugin is Beta Quality."* ([source](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin#quality))

*"This plugin is of Beta quality."* ([source](https://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html))

So, in summary: GPE support will be taken down in less than two months, and the suggested replacement is labeled "beta quality", huh?

**Is there any reliable knowledge out there regarding the roadmap of the GWT Eclipse Plugin? When do they plan to start calling it production quality?**

(Yes, I know that neither GPE or the GWT plugin is a hard prerequisite of GWT develpment in Eclipse. I'm just curious about what the official position of the GWT project will be about what to use post 2017.)